# Cannot install multiple application from NSIS installer

Tags: windows, nsis

I have been using `NSIS` for win form application to create a windows installer .Recently one of my testers reported a bug that NSIS has stop creating multiple folders in `Program Files (x86)`.

We work on multiple environments(`Staging,Prep.,Production`) previously I was able to create an installer for each on the environment but recently I believe the files in `Program Files (x86)` are getting overwritten.

**Here are the scenarios :**

I create an installer for the staging environment.Everything goes well files get installed in `Program Files (x86)`, desktop icon is created, application gets added to startup menu I am able to run and everything looks good

Now I am trying to create an installer for Pre-Production environment.After compiling the `NSIS` script and testing the installer the destination folder is not getting overridden its is taking the same path for staging.Still, after continuing with the installer this is what's happening .
No new folder is created at `Program Files (x86)`. I just have the staging folder.
A new desktop icon is created but when I am running the staging application the Pre-Production is running
Uninstalling the Staging application will uninstall both the environment

I Do not know what happening I have attached the `NSIS` script.Please have a look at it and let me know what i am doing wrong.

Thanks Regards

**Below is NSIS script:**

```
; Script generated by the HM NIS Edit Script Wizard.

; HM NIS Edit Wizard helper defines
!define PRODUCT_NAME "iContracts staging - Bulk Contract Uploader v 7.9"
!define DIR_NAME "icontracts-UCO-BulkLoader-staging"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION ""
!define PRODUCT_PUBLISHER "iContracts"
!define PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\UCO\IcnBulkUpload.exe"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\UCO\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY "HKLM"

; MUI 1.67 compatible ------
!include "MUI.nsh"

; MUI Settings
!define MUI_ABORTWARNING
!define MUI_ICON ".\Images\mine.ico"
!define MUI_UNICON "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\modern-uninstall.ico"

; Welcome page
;!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
; Directory page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
; Instfiles page
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
; Finish page
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "$INSTDIR\IcnBulkUpload.exe"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH

; Uninstaller pages
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES

; Language files
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

; MUI end ------

Name "${PRODUCT_NAME} ${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
OutFile "${PRODUCT_NAME}.exe"
;InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\${DIR_NAME}"
InstallDirRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" ""
ShowInstDetails show
ShowUnInstDetails show





Function GetDotNet
  IfFileExists "$WINDIR\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\installUtil.exe" NextStep
  MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "You must have the Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Installed to use this application. $\n$\nClick 'Open' in the following file dialog to download and run the Microsoft .NET Framework Installer..."
  ExecShell Open "http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=90&p=&SrcDisplayLang=en&SrcCategoryId=&SrcFamilyId=0856eacb-4362-4b0d-8edd-aab15c5e04f5&u=http%3a%2f%2fdownload.microsoft.com%2fdownload%2f5%2f6%2f7%2f567758a3-759e-473e-bf8f-52154438565a%2fdotnetfx.exe" SW_SHOWNORMAL
  Quit
NextStep:
FunctionEnd


Section "Check Dot Net" SEC02
Call GetDotNet

SectionEnd



Section "MainSection" SEC01

  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  SetOverwrite on
  File ".\bin\Debug\IcnBulkUpload.exe"
  File ".\bin\Debug\IcnBulkUpload.exe.config"
  File ".\mine.ICO"
  CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\IcnBulkUpload.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\mine.ICO"
  CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\${PRODUCT_NAME}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\IcnBulkUpload.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\mine.ICO"
;  CreateDirectory ""
  CreateShortCut "$STARTMENU.lnk" "$INSTDIR\IcnBulkUpload.exe"
SectionEnd

Section -AdditionalIcons
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}\Uninstall.lnk" "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
SectionEnd

Section -Post
  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" "" "$INSTDIR\IcnBulkUpload.exe"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayName" "$(^Name)"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "UninstallString" "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayIcon" "$INSTDIR\IcnBulkUpload.exe"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayVersion" "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
  WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "Publisher" "${PRODUCT_PUBLISHER}"
SectionEnd


Function un.onUninstSuccess
  HideWindow
  MessageBox MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK "$(^Name) was successfully removed from your computer."
FunctionEnd

Function un.onInit
  MessageBox MB_ICONQUESTION|MB_YESNO|MB_DEFBUTTON2 "Are you sure you want to completely remove $(^Name) and all of its components?" IDYES +2
  Abort
FunctionEnd

Section Uninstall
  Delete "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\IcnBulkUpload.exe"
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}\Uninstall.lnk"
  Delete "$STARTMENU.lnk"
  Delete "$DESKTOP\iContracts.lnk"
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}\iContracts.lnk"

  RMDir /r "$SMPROGRAMS\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
  RMDir /r "$INSTDIR"
  RMDir ""

  DeleteRegKey ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}"
  SetAutoClose true
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Stack Overflow suggests Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples for a good reason –  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nobody wants to go through an overly large example to spot what might be the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The `InstallDirRegKey` attribute changes `$InstDir` if it finds a existing installation! Use a unique value for PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY for each install type and use that as the path used by `InstallDirRegKey`.